# How do I apply OrderBy on an IQueryable using a string column name within a generic extension method?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> ApplySortFilter<T, TResult>(this IQueryable<T> query, string columnName)
  where T : EntityObject
{
  var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");
  var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(param,columnName);

  var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda(body, param);
  return query.OrderBy(sortExpression);
}
```

Because the type for OrderBy is not inferred from sortExpression I need to specify it something like this at run time:

```
var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<T, TSortColumn>(body, param);
```

Or

```
return query.OrderBy<T, TSortColumn>(sortExpression);
```

I don't think this is possible however as TSortColumn can only be determined during runtime.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12920204/1139347) what you're looking for, but take a look. Cheers

Comment: @JTew  How can i implement a second order by clause..say orderby id then by date

Answer (score 120, accepted):

We did something similar (not 100% the same, but similar) in a LINQ to SQL project. Here's the code:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering, params object[] values) {
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(ordering);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
}
```

We didn't actually use a generic, we had a known class, but it should work on a generic (I've put the generic placeholder where it should be).

**Edit:** For descending order, pass in `OrderByDescending` instead of "OrderBy":

```
MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderByDescending", new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
```

Comment: Heh no prob, I can't assign the answer to myself anyways :)

Comment: for descending order, pass in "OrderByDescending" instead of "OrderBy"

MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderByDescending", ...

Comment: This worked just fine, but the following was just a really nice clean code example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby

Comment: @Aaron Powell How can i implement a second order by clause..say orderby id then by date

Comment: @SRJ you'd do that by using the `ThenBy` method on LINQ, so on the 2nd last line having `"ThenBy"` rather than `"OrderBy"`.

Comment: Is this prone to code injection of any kind (does it need validating)?

Comment: What is the parameter `values` for?

Comment: Hi. i try to do the same task. I have tried to use your code, but i have one problem like (System.Linq.Expressions.IArgumentProvider.ArgumentCount = '((System.Linq.Expressions.IArgumentProvider)resultExp).ArgumentCount' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException')
which throws before return statement. This exception may find only in debug mode.
Any help please?

Comment: values are not used

Answer (score 32):

You can also use Dynamic Linq

Info here 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

C# download here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx

Then just add the using Linq.Dynamic; and you automatically get 2 additional extension methods that can be used like this

```
return query.OrderBy("StringColumnName");
```

Comment: Thanks, I had seen Linq.Dynamic about in a sample at Phil Haack's site but was unsure about it. I'll have a play with this over the weekend.

Comment: As an alternate the Systems.Linq.Dynamic.dll can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic

Answer (score 14):

I've extended your functions to add support for Child Properties.

```
private static LambdaExpression GenerateSelector<TEntity>(String propertyName, out Type resultType) where TEntity : class
{
    // Create a parameter to pass into the Lambda expression (Entity => Entity.OrderByField).
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "Entity");
    //  create the selector part, but support child properties
    PropertyInfo property;
    Expression propertyAccess;
    if (propertyName.Contains('.'))
    {
            // support to be sorted on child fields.
            String[] childProperties = propertyName.Split('.');
            property = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(childProperties[0]);
            propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
            for (int i = 1; i < childProperties.Length; i++)
            {
                    property = property.PropertyType.GetProperty(childProperties[i]);
                    propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(propertyAccess, property);
            }
    }
    else
    {
            property = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(propertyName);
            propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    }
    resultType = property.PropertyType;                     
    // Create the order by expression.
    return Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
}

private static MethodCallExpression GenerateMethodCall<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> source, string methodName, String fieldName) where TEntity : class
{
    Type type = typeof(TEntity);
    Type selectorResultType;
    LambdaExpression selector = GenerateSelector<TEntity>(fieldName, out selectorResultType);
    MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName,
                                    new Type[] { type, selectorResultType },
                                    source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector));
    return resultExp;
}
```

You can use these functions like:

```
GenerateMethodCall<TEntity>(source, "OrderByDescending", fieldName);
```

Comment: You are my hero !!

Comment: gotta love smart people

Comment: I tried this code and it does work with one Child, but not with more than one, e.g. it works with sorting on x.String and x.Object.String, but not with sorting on x.Object.Object.String.

Comment: To handle a child property at an arbitrary level of depth in the object graph, this will need recursion for the section that checks the child property (the IF). Mixing recursion and reflection isn't my cup of tea :)

Answer (score 8):

I used your idea for extension method for OrderBy. But in case of "many to many" I am getting error. For example you have table Site, Customer and  Customer_site.
For given Site I want to sort by customer name and in OrderBy extension (when I pass "site.customer" where customer is navigation property) I get error in line: propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(propertyAccess, property);

This is what I use (with some enhancements :-) ):

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string orderByValues) where TEntity : class
{
  IQueryable<TEntity> returnValue = null;

  string orderPair = orderByValues.Trim().Split(',')[0];
  string command = orderPair.ToUpper().Contains("DESC") ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";

  var type = typeof(TEntity);
  var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");

  string propertyName = (orderPair.Split(' ')[0]).Trim();

  System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property;
  MemberExpression propertyAccess;

  if (propertyName.Contains('.'))
  {
    // support to be sorted on child fields. 
    String[] childProperties = propertyName.Split('.');
    property = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(childProperties[0]);
    propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);

    for (int i = 1; i < childProperties.Length; i++)
    {
      Type t = property.PropertyType;
      if (!t.IsGenericType)
      {
        property = t.GetProperty(childProperties[i]);
      }
      else
      {
        property = t.GetGenericArguments().First().GetProperty(childProperties[i]);
      }

      propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(propertyAccess, property);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
  }

  var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

  var resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },

  source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));

  returnValue = source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);

  if (orderByValues.Trim().Split(',').Count() > 1)
  {
    // remove first item
    string newSearchForWords = orderByValues.ToString().Remove(0, orderByValues.ToString().IndexOf(',') + 1);
    return source.OrderBy(newSearchForWords);
  }

  return returnValue;
}
```

Regards

Slobodan

Answer (score 6):

It seems that [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx) is the way to do it, now to verify that:

```
// ***** OrderBy(company => company) *****
// Create an expression tree that represents the expression
// 'whereCallExpression.OrderBy(company => company)'
MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "OrderBy",
    new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType, queryableData.ElementType },
    whereCallExpression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string>>(pe, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));
// ***** End OrderBy *****
```

Comment: damnit, 34 seconds behind! :P

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to add  "System.Linq.Dynamic" package then,
Too easy without any complication,

fisrt insatll package "System.Linq.Dynamic" from NuGet package manager then
try as below as your need,

Ex:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetWithInclude(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate,
                    List<string> sortBy, int pageNo, int pageSize = 12, params string[] include)
        {
            try
            {
                var numberOfRecordsToSkip = pageNo * pageSize;
                var dynamic = DbSet.AsQueryable();

                foreach (var s in include)
                {
                    dynamic.Include(s);
                }
                 return dynamic.OrderBy("CreatedDate").Skip(numberOfRecordsToSkip).Take(pageSize);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this code a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1670085/5852630

This code works with sequential sorting: first execute "OrderBy", then "ThenBy"(Not "OrderBy"!)

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string orderByValues) where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> returnValue = null;

    string[] orderPairs = orderByValues.Trim().Split(',');

    Expression resultExpression = source.Expression;

    string strAsc = "OrderBy";
    string strDesc = "OrderByDescending";

    foreach (string orderPair in orderPairs)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderPair))
            continue;

        string[] orderPairArr = orderPair.Trim().Split(' ');

        string propertyName = orderPairArr[0].Trim();
        string orderNarrow = orderPairArr.Length > 1 ? orderPairArr[1].Trim() : string.Empty;

        string command = orderNarrow.ToUpper().Contains("DESC") ? strDesc : strAsc;

        Type type = typeof(TEntity);
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");

        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property;
        Expression propertyAccess;

        if (propertyName.Contains('.'))
        {
            // support to be sorted on child fields. 
            String[] childProperties = propertyName.Split('.');
            property = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(childProperties[0]);
            propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);

            for (int i = 1; i < childProperties.Length; i++)
            {
                Type t = property.PropertyType;
                if (!t.IsGenericType)
                {
                    property = t.GetProperty(childProperties[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    property = t.GetGenericArguments().First().GetProperty(childProperties[i]);
                }

                propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(propertyAccess, property);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
            propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        }

        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(object))
        {
            propertyAccess = Expression.Call(propertyAccess, "ToString", null);
        }

        LambdaExpression orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

        resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType == typeof(object) ? typeof(string) : property.PropertyType },
            resultExpression, Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));

        strAsc = "ThenBy";
        strDesc = "ThenByDescending";
    }

    returnValue = source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);

    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my adaptation from [@Davy Landman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11098/davy-landman)'s answer (I wanted an extension method) and I simplified a bit.

```
public static IQueryable<T> SortBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, 
                                      String propertyName, 
                                      WebControls.SortDirection direction)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)) return source;

        // Create a parameter to pass into the Lambda expression
        //(Entity => Entity.OrderByField).
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "Entity");

        //  create the selector part, but support child properties (it works without . too)
        String[] childProperties = propertyName.Split('.');
        MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, childProperties[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < childProperties.Length; i++)
        {
            property = Expression.Property(property, childProperties[i]);
        }

        LambdaExpression selector = Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);

        string methodName = (direction > 0) ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";

        MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName,
                                        new Type[] { source.ElementType, property.Type },
                                        source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector));

        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
    }
```

It can be used like this:

```
gridview1.DataSource = DbContext.TB_CARS.SortBy("model", SortDirection.Descending);
//OR
gridview1.DataSource = DbContext.TB_CARS.SortBy("owner.first_name", 0);
```