# How to build a linq query from string?

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse string into a LINQ query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399967/parse-string-into-a-linq-query)

Iam trying to build a linq query, from string but confused.

From the below query string MyRptStrng is having the conditions...

```
string MyLnqBuildStr="(from DataRow DR1 in MyEmpTbl.AsEnumerable() orderby Convert.ToInt32(DR1['emp_no']) where " + ???????MyRptStrng + " select DR1).ToList()";


var GRNMultiRslt = MyLnqBuildStr;

DataTable GRNPrtDTB = GRNMultiRslt.CopyToDataTable();
```

And Iam getting the error - char cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in generic type...

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think [query expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx) are strings?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: presumably LOGAN is loading the query from some other resource (like a database table).

Answer (score 2):

This won't work. At all. You can't (in any easy way) execute a string that contains a query expression. Perhaps you want to use SQL instead?

Comment: SQL Ican do..Thanks for all replies..

Comment: he can actually. I know this question is old but I suggest trying the `Gridify` library.
https://github.com/alirezanet/Gridify