# How to OrderBy in LINQ to Entities (EF4.1) when I only know the property name at runtime?

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a linq query of objects of a known type and I need to sort it based on a property of the object.  The problem is I only know the property name at runtime and as a string.

ex.

```
IQueryable<Thing> thing = from t in ctx.Things select t;
t.OrderBy(t => t.Name);   // This would work if I knew the property at compile time...
t.OrderBy("Name asc");    // But this is what I really need!  and it doesn't work.
```

Is there a way to do this for LINQ to Entities?  I'm using entity framework 4.1

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gener#308561

Comment: Thanks, that should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

There are two

1. `.OrderBy(m => m.Name)`
2. `.OrderByDescending(m => m.Name)`

First one represents Ascending, the other one descending.

Hope it helps.

What about try this one ! Let's see if helps

```
    Expression orderByProperty = Expression.Property(prm, sortBy);

    // get the paged records
    IQueryable<PostingListItemDto> query = be.buskerPosting
    .Where(posting => posting.buskerAccount.cmsMember.nodeId == m.Id)
    .OrderBy(orderByExpression)
```

Comment: I don't know the property name at compile time, so that won't work for me.