# Filtering large collection of Unknown type

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, reflection

I want to filter a large collection of unknown type

```
List<object> _list;
```

I need to search in the values of multiple properties which are also passed on runtime

```
 List<SearchField> _searchFields;
```

SearchField basically has a string property "ProprtyName"

```
    class SearchField
    {
        public string PropertyName{get; set;}
    }
```

I have tried

```
_list.Select(localItem => (from searchField in SearchFields
            let displayProperty = (from PropertyDescriptor property in properties
            where property.Name.ToLower() == searchField.FieldName.ToLower()
            select property).FirstOrDefault()
            where displayproperty != null
            let valueBinding = new BindingEvaluator<string>
            (
            new Binding(displayproperty.Name) 
            { 
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Source = localItem 
            })
           let obj = valueBinding.GetDynamicValue(localItem,true) ?? string.Empty
            select new IndexItem
            {
                SearchField = searchField,
                Text = obj,
                Item = localItem,
            }}).ToList()))
```

but will large collection like 20,000 items it's taking 8 seconds which is totally unacceptable. Please suggest where I am doing wrong and what should I do to optimize it.

Comment: Reflection is very slow... nuff said :).

Comment: What are the sizes of `_searchFields` and `properties` collections?

Comment: size is more like 20,000 items

Comment: Also, you're computing the `displayProperty` for each `localItem` and `searchField`, while it doesn't depend on a `localItem` and maybe computed outside the `_list.Select`.

Comment: @gaurawerma That is, **each** of `_list`, `_searchFields` and `properties` contains about 20000 items?

Comment: only _list contains large data. _searchFields and properties have very few data. _searchFields are like 2 or three

Comment: I am using displayProperty to know get the case sensitive property name

Comment: _searchFields contains the list of property names I need to search in the _list

Answer (score 2):

Order by string column name:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering) {
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(ordering);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
}
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gene)

Misunderstood the question.
You might want to try [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) for this.

```
 repository.Where( "@0 == @1", property.Name, value );
```

Comment: yourCollection.OrderBy("PropertyName").ToList()

Comment: but I have multiple properties for which I need to search.

Comment: in second example create a filtering string like ` (propname = @0) && (prop2name == @1)' and pass values to where method