# How to add an AND/OR expression to the following dynamic linq expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees, dynamic-linq

T is a type that may or may not have a specific property, lets say 'City'. For the types that have a property named 'City', I would like to restrict the records such that only residents of the Gotham are returned and they are sorted.

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering, params object[] values) 
{

    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(ordering);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
    MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), 
                "OrderBy", 
                new     Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, 
                source.Expression, 
                Expression.Quote(orderByExp));


    string propertyToRestrictOn = "City";
    string restrictedValue = "Gotham";
    var restrictedProperty = type.GetProperty(propertyToRestrictOn);
    if(null ! = restrictedProperty )
    {
      // TODO: What to add here so than only those records are returned that have a 
      // property named City and the value is 'Gotham'???
    }

   return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
}
```

if possible please name/link some helpful literature here as well just in case I have to create more complex queries i.e. mix And/OR

The code was borrowed from 
[How do I apply OrderBy on an IQueryable using a string column name within a generic extension method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gene)

Comment: I think you should the title of your question, since it's not actually about AND or OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this harder than you have to. In the first part of your code (the `OrderBy()`), you don't actually need to generate the whole query expression, just the lambda inside it.
And in the second part (the optional `Where()`) you can do pretty much the same thing, just add `Expression.Equal()` and `Expression.Constant()`:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var property = type.GetProperty(ordering);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
    // necessary for value types to work
    var cast = Expression.Convert(propertyAccess, typeof(object));
    var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(cast, parameter);

    IQueryable<T> result = source.OrderBy(orderByExp);

    string propertyToRestrictOn = "City";
    string restrictedValue = "Gotham";
    var restrictedProperty = type.GetProperty(propertyToRestrictOn);
    if (restrictedProperty != null)
    {
        var restrictionParameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var restrictionPropertyAccess =
            Expression.MakeMemberAccess(restrictionParameter, restrictedProperty);
        var restrictionEquality =
            Expression.Equal(restrictionPropertyAccess,
                             Expression.Constant(restrictedValue));
        var whereExp =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(restrictionEquality, restrictionParameter);

        result = result.Where(whereExp);
    }

   return result;
}
```

Also, if your method is going to do more than just ordering, I think you shouldn't call it `OrderBy()`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure if I have understood you correctly, but I think I was in the same situation a few months ago.
The posted code  [here](http://passiondev.wordpress.com/2012/10/27/linq-expressiontrees/)  was my solution.

I think you should be especially interested in line 24.

---

Edit:

```
PropertyInfo p = ... // I used reflection in my examply to get properties with a certain Attribute

var expressionParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeClass), "lambda");    
var parameter = new [] { expressionParameter };

var propertyAccess = Expression.Property(expressionParameter, p);
var nullCheck = Expression.NotEqual(propertyAccess, Expression.Constant(null, p.PropertyType));
var nullCheckLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeClass, Boolean>>(nullCheck, parameter);

var containsMethodInfo = typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(String) });
var contains = Expression.Call(propertyAccess, containsMethodInfo, Expression.Constant("ell"));
var containsLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeClass, Boolean>>(contains, new[] { expressionParameter });

var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeClass, Boolean>>(
// line 24 
Expression.AndAlso(nullCheckLambda.Body, containsLambda.Body), parameter);

Console.WriteLine(predicate.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're half-way there already. You have the ordered expression already, so you're just going to use the `Queryable.OrderBy` expression call in a `Queryable.Where` expression (or vice-versa, doesn't really matter).

```
if(null != restrictedProperty )
{
    var notEqualExp = Expression.NotEqual(parameter,
                            Expression.Constant(restrictedValue, typeof(string)));
    resultExp = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), 
            "Where", 
            new Type[] { type }, 
            resultExp, 
            Expression.Lambda(notEqualExp, parameter));
}
```

Haven't worked with building Expressions by hand in a while, so this is purely being done from memory. However, it should at least get you started and give you something to work with.

P.S. I would actually perform this check BEFORE the `OrderBy` method call. That way you end up with `Queryably.Where(...).OrderBy(...)` instead. But I guess if this is getting translated by the provider anyway, then shouldn't matter. However, just something I'd do to reduce any ambiguity of the generated query.