# Custom OrderBy Due to Hundreds of Columns

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have a table which has hundreds of columns (like `FirstName` and `LastName`).

All this data is displayed as a `GridView` with listing. I've made use of the `SortCommand` event which has the `e.SortExpression`, but I can't fathom how to use it in an `OrderBy` function since after inputting a lambda expression. IntelliSense shows me all the hundreds of columns instead of the one I need - which I only have at run-time.

How do I use the `Func<TSource, TKey>` selector the `OrderBy` functions expects from me to let it know that the string `e.SortExpression` is the column that needs to be sorted?

Example of what I essentially mean:

```
private void dataGrid_SortCommand(object source, DataGridSortCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var users = new UsersEntities().UsersTable.OrderBy(x => "x."+e.SortExpression);
    FillDataGrid(users); 
}
```

Update:
I've come to understand that the way in which I'm looking to accomplish this is using Expression trees, and I'm hoping someone can provide the exact solution.

Update 2:
I've found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gene). Turns out my question was a duplicate and to add to that, badly worded. Thanks to everyone.

And I've also just noticed that ken's offered pretty damning evidence that I should use dynamic linq. I'll consider doing so in the future, but I couldn't help but notice how fun it is to experiment with Expression trees rather than rely on libraries to do them for me. At this stage, as I'm still new to Expression trees this is a perfect opportunity to utilize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dynamic linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) That would allow you to do an `OrderBy` based on a `string`.

**Edit**

See my comment. Using dynamic linq, your solution could be as easy as:

```
var users = new UsersEntities().UsersTable.OrderBy(e.SortExpression);
```

Comment: Any chance of being able to stick with pure Ado.Net? I have an unexplainable distaste for SQL as a language.

Comment: @Agon - I'm confused... are you using an ORM (LINQ-to-SQL, EntityFramework)? It looks like you are. Dynamic linq works with ORMs.

Comment: I'm using purely an Entity (entity framwork). And prefer to stick to C# as much as humanely possible.

Comment: @Agon - Dynamic Linq and Entity Framework work well together. Dynamic Linq != dynamic SQL. It is a library that builds expressions from strings, and those expressions can be used in IQueryable Where and OrderBy methods.

Comment: Thank you, ken, for explaining. I've chosen your reply as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create LINQ expressions easily as long as only logical ANDs are involved in where clauses. Simply repeat the `Where` clause!

```
// Filter
var query = new UsersEntities().UsersTable.Select(x => x);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nameFilter) {
    query = query.Where(x => x.Name == nameFilter);
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(zipFilter) {
    query = query.Where(x => x.Zip == zipFilter);
}

// Sorting
switch (sortField)
{
    case "Name":
        query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
        break;
    case "Zip":
        query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Zip);
        break;
}
```

---

You could also create an expression tree dynamically, but this is not very obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think it's practical to have hundreds of redundant lines, the very concept of programming kinda loses its purpose.
I've been trying for the past hour now to get this done using expressions, but I'm completely new to the topic of Expression trees (only found out about them after creating this question) so I'm having a hard time.
But this method is basically exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: See: [How to: Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but I've been going hard at that exact page (and a dozen more) for that whole hour now, and still unsuccessful.