# How to query with Boolean using LINQ

Tags: c#, database, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table with `Sub-Categories` of Bike (Mountain Bikes, Touring Bikes, Road Bikes, ...) and I created a column `isSelected` with `Boolean` data type. I want to set up in Database when `isSelected` = `true` each `Sub-Categories` is matched with it will be show on Homepage and vice versa.

```
IQueryable<ProductSubcategory> list = null;

if (Id == null)
{
    list = BikesDB.ProductSubcategories;
}
else
{
    int id = Id.Value;
    list = BikesDB.ProductSubcategories.Where(m => m.ProductSubcategoryID == id
                                                   && m.NameofBike == Name
                                                   && m.isSelected == true);
}

var bikes = list.AsEnumerable().Select(
             p => new Bike { Id = p.ProductSubcategoryID, Name = p.NameofBike });

var viewModel = new CategoriesIndexViewModel
                {
                    NumberOfModel = bikes.Count(),
                    NameofBike = bikes.Select(b=>b.Name).ToList(),
                    Bikes = bikes.ToList()
                };

return this.View(viewModel);
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: For example, when I clicked `false` of `Mountain Bikes`, it still display on Homepage of Web Application. How can I disappear `Mountain Bikes` when I set it `false` in Database?

Comment: you mean like:  `m.isSelected == true`

Comment: @johnb003 Exactly, that's what I mean!

Comment: You want to create [a dynamic LINQ expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077888/building-linq-generic-queries).

Comment: This question seems specific to your data, and has a lot of irrelevant information. Maybe you should revise your question so that you're showing just the class, an enumerator with a few items, and how you're filtering the list, print the results and show what's not working about it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `isSelected` is actually set? I think your linq expression looks fine. It should already correctly only select items where `isSelected == true`.

I'd look at your list in the debugger right before the query is done and make sure it has what you think it has.

OR you're running the first branch: `if (Id == null)` and your list is not filtered by the `isSelected` condition.

Comment: It still show full of items not only select item where `isSelected == true`. I don't know where I am wrong these codes above!

Comment: Do you even change the value of `isSelected` in your database? (which shouldn't even be done, that's horrible design)

Comment: No, I don't change it @JeroenVannevel