# "System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null" in MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When I am developing a basic Employee application of CRUD Operations using jQuery dialog and Entity Framework, I am getting two type of error when I am debugging and when I am building the solution, I know they both linked to each other but I am not able to figure out

**Error 1 when building:**

*The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly*

**This the code(in Model class):**

```
public IEnumerable<tblEmployee> GetEmployeePage(int pageNumber, int pageSize, string searchCriteria)
{
    if (pageNumber < 1)
        pageNumber = 1;

    return testEmp.tblEmployees
      .OrderBy(searchCriteria) //I am getting error here//
      .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
      .Take(pageSize)
      .ToList();
}
```

**Error 2 when debugging:**

*System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.*

**The code as below (in View):**

```
@model Emp_Mvc_Application.Models.PagedEmployeeModel 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize);
    grid.Bind(Model.TblEmp, autoSortAndPage: false, rowCount: Model.TotalRows);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search criteria needs to be a lambda expression e.g.

`OrderBy(e => e.EmployeeID)`

Instead of a `string` try this

```
public IEnumerable<tblEmployee> GetEmployeePage(int pageNumber, int pageSize, Func<tblEmployee, object> searchCriteria)
{
if (pageNumber < 1)
        pageNumber = 1;

    return testEmp.tblEmployees
      .OrderBy(searchCriteria) 
      .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
      .Take(pageSize)
      .ToList();
}
```

Call it like so:

`var result = GetEmployeePage(1, 10, e => e.EmployeeId)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing a string in as your orderby criteria - that method is expecting a delegate. That seems like a misleading error but I believe that is your issue.

For example:

```
.OrderBy(e => e.LastName)
```

If you need to be able to sort by a string criteria you may want to look here-
[How do I apply OrderBy on an IQueryable using a string column name within a generic extension method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gene)