# is it possible to convert Int32 to String?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to `convert Int32` to `string`?

I am having difficulties with this line of the code, where I am trying to convert `Int32` to `string`.

```
var listOrder = daa.OrderByDescending(i => i.Times).ToList().Convert.ToString().OrderByDescending(jtSorting);
```

`i.Times` is `Int32` and I have to pass `jSorting` parameter which is string.

I get this error when I compile:

"Does not contain a defination for 'Convert' and no extension method 'Convert' accepting a first argument of type"

Full controller code for your inspection:

```
public JsonResult TopPlayedInVenueList1(string name = "", string ArtistName = "", int jtStartIndex = 0, int jtPageSize = 0, string jtSorting = null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated == true)
            {
                string Path = @"C:\\5Newwithdate-records.xls";
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= '" + 
                                                            Path + "';Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + 
                                                            "Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;" + (char)34 + "");
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);

                System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
                da.Fill(data);
                con.Close();

                List<TopPlayed> daa = new List<TopPlayed>();
                foreach (DataRow p in data.Rows)
                {
                    TopPlayed top = new TopPlayed()
                    {
                        TrackID = Convert.ToInt32(p.Field<double>("TrackID")),
                        TrackName = p.Field<string>("TrackName"),
                        ArtistName = p.Field<string>("ArtistName"),
                        Times = Convert.ToInt32(p.Field<double>("Times"))
                    };

                    daa.Add(top);
                }

                ///// var newlist = daa.OrderByDescending(i => i.Times).ToList().GetRange(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize);

                var newlist = daa.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(jtSorting).OrderByDescending(i => i.Times).ToList();

                return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = newlist, TotalRecordCount = daa.Count });
```

View Code of jTable Datatable:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1').jtable({

        title: 'NSM Biling Report List',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 100,
        sorting: true,
      //  defaultSorting: 'Times ASC',

        actions: {
            listAction: '@Url.Action("TopPlayedInVenueList1")'

        },
        fields: {
            TrackID: {
                title: 'Track ID',
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                resize: false,
                tooltip: 'Track Name'
            },
            TrackName: {
                title: 'Track Name',
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                resize: false,
                tooltip: 'Track Name'
            },
            ArtistName: {
                title: 'Artist Name',
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                resize: false,
                tooltip: 'Track Name'
            },
            Times: {
                title: 'Times',
                tooltip: 'Artist Name'
            }
        }
    });

    $('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1').jtable('load', {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            ArtistName: $('#ArtistName').val()
        });
    });

    //Load all records when page is first shown
    $('#LoadRecordsButton').click();
});
```

OrderByExtensions

```
namespace NSM.BackOffice.Controllers
{
public static class OrderByExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var property = type.GetProperty(ordering);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var property = type.GetProperty(ordering);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderByDescending", new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
    }
}
```

}

I am fresh with c# so if you could please let me know a workout to get this to work. thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a .ToString() method on the Int32 object directly.

Comment: @Lasse: That does not work within that Linq query.

Comment: I know, but it answers the question asked, twice.

Comment: Why are you ordering twice?

Comment: LasseV.Karlsen and Robert - thanks for your input!

Comment: @TimSchmelter - thanks for your question.. I have to order it twice because I have to pass this `jtSorting` which is a `null string` but default as by passing it, it enables sorting on the server-side. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can remove almost 50% of your code and still return same JSON result set. Why are you making all those list and not using them.

Comment: @peer thanks - yes I was experitmenting different techniques to pass on the `jtSorting` parameter but none of them worked. I have tied up the code.. Can you please help to pass on the `jtSorting` parameter?

Answer (score 3):

You can call `ToString` during projection in [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var listOrder = daa.OrderByDescending(i => i.Times).Select(c=>c.Times.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks.. I have to pass `jtSorting` parameter in it which is a string. I have updated a full code on mine.

Comment: You need c.Times.ToString(), please check my updated answer and use that query

Answer (score 2):

This part:

```
OrderByDescending(i => i.Times).ToList().Convert.ToString()
```

looks very strange. `Convert` here is not a property and not a method call. You might probably want this instead:

```
OrderByDescending(i => i.Times).ToList().Select(x => x.ToString())
```

**Update.** Following up discussion in comments - here is how to use the extension method implemented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gene). Declare a static class somewhere in the project like this:

```
public static class OrderByExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering) {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var property = type.GetProperty(ordering);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering) {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var property = type.GetProperty(ordering);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderByDescending", new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
    }
}
```

Make sure this class is visible inside the `TopPlayedInVenueList1`, if not - use `using` to make so. After that you should be able to do this with any `IQueryable<>`:

```
.OrderByDescending(jtSorting);
```

Comment: that's great and thanks.. It won't let me to pass `jtSorting` string parameter in it

Comment: @pv619, now I see your problem. All right, passing property name into `OrderBy` is a well known question, which has a lot of answers. Check out [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gene), for example

Comment: sorry for not being clear.. thanks for the link and I checked  the post it's somewhat different and I am not sure what to do. Can you help? I have to add `jtSorting` parameters so that it enables on server-side. thanks again :)

Comment: @pv619, add where? Enables what? As far as I can see you are trying to order a collection of objects by their property, and you have a string with property name. Is that right?

Comment: @pv619, then the link above is exactly what you need. Check out first answer. It defines an extension methods `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` accepting string for property name. So what you need to do is: 1) Create the same extension method somewhere in your project, 2) call it exactly as you arecalling it now

Comment: thanks for getting back and let me do that and I'll get back to you asap. :) cheers

Comment: I tried it man but it started to give me all sorts of errors.. i.e. `var` is not defined, an `object` reference is required for `ordering` , same errors for `parameters`.. man i'm not too sure how I can get this sorting thing to work.

Comment: here's the [link](http://s9.postimg.org/x6fzuaa7j/Capture.png) in using the extension method. I see what you mean, so even if I can get this code to work then it would be great.

Comment: @pv619, you really need to read some tutorial on exntesion methods. Extension method should be a part of some dedicated static class. Do you have one?

Comment: thanks - Yes I do have them but they're being used for other functions. So I created a brand new Class and in it I added the extension that gave me soo many errors.

Comment: @pv619, please see the update - hope its clear now. If still not - please look up some extension methods usage example

Comment: man thanks for your answer and help throughout, I created a brand new `Controller` class of `OrderByExtensions` without any issue. I feel awkward for asking and sorry for the trouble.. it still won't let me use `var list = daa.ToList().OrderByDescending(jtSorting);` says "cannot be inferred from the usage". I think we're almost there! and thanks a million once again! - u been an awesome help :)

Comment: I used this `var newlist = daa.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(jtSorting).OrderByDescending(i => i.Times).ToList();` without any errors and compiled fine but it didn't display any data and the datatable gave out this message out "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: name" is that because jtSorting is a null string by default? any idea?? I think we are missing a small bit.. almost there! ehehe :)

Comment: @pv619, at what line of code is the exception falling?

Comment: Hi.. and thanks for getting back :) this is the line that keeps on giving error: `var list = daa.ToList().OrderByDescending(jtSorting);` when I use `.OrderByDescending(jtSorting);` and gives out **Cannot be inferred from the usage"**

Comment: as I am using `IQueryable<T>` so I tried `.AsQueryable()` like this `var newlist = daa.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(jtSorting).OrderByDescending(i => i.Times).ToList();` then it complies fine but doesn't display any data and the jQuery jTable gives out this message `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: name`. The only `null` parameter that I am using is `jtSorting`. I have updated my full code for your inspection. And above all thanks a million! :)

Comment: Do we have to declare `jtSorting` in the `OrderByExtensions` class? so that it takes all the `.OrderByDescending(jtSorting);` arguments? thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You jsSorting parameter is for sorting datatables, not IEnumerables:
Try this:

```
data.DefaultView.Sort = jsSorting;
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion and it works but it won't let me pass `jtSorting` parameter in it which is a string.

Comment: thanks for getting back :) - I tried what you suggested, it seems to be loading the sorting but it ain't really doing it. I have updated my code with your code :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert your list object to a string:

```
var listOrder = daa.OrderByDescending(i => i.Times).ToList().Convert.ToString();
```

What you may want (and I don't know your requirements is):

```
var listOrder = daa.OrderByDescending(i => i.Times).Select(i => i.Times.ToString()).ToList();
```

Which would give you a list of strings.

---

As per your comment, if the technique noted is beyond you, you could do this (and this might be fine if there are a limited number of columns that you want to sort by):

```
List<TopPlayed> sorted;

switch (jtSorting)
{
   case "Times":
      sorted = daa.OrderByDescending(i => i.Times).ToList();
      break;
   case "Other":
      sorted = daa.OrderByDescending(i => i.Other).ToList();
      break;
    default:
      //Oops.  Do something appropriate here.
}

// etc.
```

Comment: thanks :) it works great but I got to pass `jtSorting` parameter in it for it to enable sorting.

Comment: OK, wasn't so clear.  You might try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet

Comment: sorry for not being clear and thanks for the link.. it seems to be advanced level of c# I am not exactly sure how I can pass `jtSoring` string parameter using those techniques.

Comment: thanks for getting back :) - I tried your update and it seems to be loading but it's not doing it. I have updated my code above with your fix.

Comment: You're still returning the list variable rather than the sorted variable.

Comment: Looking at your code in more detail, if you just sort your datatable first (before making the list), then this should work...

Comment: thanks Paddy - I removed the list and I have updated my code above.. man it still don't work. I'm lost! :(

Comment: If I were you, I would start by tidying up your code - remove the list parts altogether, as you are not using them.  Sort the default view on your datatable and use that.  Tidying up the code should help you to sort out where you are going wrong as you debug through.

Comment: yeah man that's one main thing that needs to be done properly. thanks.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Pretty much everything in C# inherits from `object`, which has a `ToString()` method. Not everything provides a particularly useful implementation (some things just print their type name, particularly collections) but `Int32` does. Therefore, `i.Times.ToString()` will give you the string version.

Comment: _"some things just print their type name, particularly collections"_ _Everything_ returns it's fully qualified type name **which does not override ToString** since that is the default implementation of `object.ToString`.

Comment: Well, yes. What I meant is that some things have a useful override, like `int`, and some things don't. With a question about something as basic as whether `int32` has a `.ToString()`, I thought it best not to get too complicated.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Linq

```
daa.OrderByDescending(i => i.Times.ToString())
daa.OrderByDescending(i => (string)i.Times)
```

If you use Linq on EF

```
daa.OrderByDescending(i => SqlFunctions.StringFormat((double?)i.Times))
```

Comment: If an expression `x` is of type `int`, it cannot be converted to type `string` with a conversion expression (cast) `(string)x`. So one of your examples is illegal. The syntax `(string)x` is useful only if the compile-time type of `x` is a base class of `string` (that would be `object`) or some interface that `string` implements, and when you know that the run-time type of `x` is really going to be `string`.