# Sorting List<T> on a member of type<U> decided at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, generics

I have a type Customer as

```
Class Customer
{
    string Name;
    Address address;
    ...
}
```

And class Address as

```
Class Address  
{  
    string Street;  
    int House;  
    ....  
}
```

I am creating a list of Customer as

```
List<Customer> CustSource= new List<Customer>();
```

Then I bind CustSource to a repeater.
    Repeater have a column named 'Street' bound with CustSource.address.Street, 'House Number' bound with CustSource.address.HouseNum, 'Name' bound with CustSource.Name and so on.
    I want to sort the the binding source i.e. CustSource on a field decided at runtime. I know it can be done as `CustSource.OrderBy(x=>x.Name)` when I know which field to sort on at compile time, but to decide the field at runtime and sort, have written an extension method with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gene) article.

Problem is, When I sort it on the primitive property of Customer class like 'Name', it works fine, but how can I sort on the Address.Street property of CustSource?

Comment: You should rewrite the title. This has nothing to do with `List<T>`.

Comment: are you within an asp.net context? if so, please add tags accordingly!

Comment: how else could you sort a list if not at runtime?!

Comment: I think by run time, he means to sort programatically by user click on  column headers(some sort of using dynamic or reflection); but there are too many columns to handle. Am I right?

Comment: binding identifiers to the headers to know what to sort on on postback is semi-dynamic. adding the whole reflection path to the gui (and set it all the layers down) would be ... too much ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/how-do-i-apply-orderby-on-an-iqueryable-using-a-string-column-name-within-a-gene/308863#308863), I was able to solve the query(I have linked to this SO post in my question also, but was not patient enough to go through all the answers, my bad).
Quoting the person who posted this answer, all I needed was
`if (propertyName.Contains('.'))
    {
            // support to be sorted on child fields.
            String[] childProperties = propertyName.Split('.');
            property = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(childProperties[0]);
            propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
            for (int i = 1; i < childProperties.Length; i++)
            {
                    property = property.PropertyType.GetProperty(childProperties[i]);
                    propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(propertyAccess, property);
            }
    }`

Looks like writing 'Child Properties' in my question would have made it easy to answer.