# Setting a dynamic sort name field in a linq query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to be able to get an `OrderBy` query working with a lambda expression so that I get a SQL query with the TOP(n) key word (big performance boost).

I am able to do this if I specifiy ...

```
PaginatedList = query.OrderBy(x => x.QuoteID).Skip(() => skipValue).Take(() => pageSize)
```

But because I want the orderBy field to be dynamic through a UI selection of a name I want to do something like this:

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(Data.Quote).GetProperty(sortName);
Expression<Func<Data.Quote, object>> orderField = x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null);
PaginatedList = query.OrderBy(orderField).Skip(() => skipValue).Take(() => pageSize)
```

This gives me the error:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object
>   GetValue(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression."

I tried this that's not of type `Expression<Func<T, object>>`

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(Data.Quote).GetProperty(sortName);
Func<Data.Quote, object> orderField = x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null);
PaginatedList = query.OrderBy(x => orderField).Skip(() => skipValue).Take(() => pageSize)
```

And I get this error:

> "Unable to create a constant value of type [...]. Only primitive types
>   or enumeration types are supported in this context"

I'm sure there is a way to achieve this but at the moment not sure how.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions everyone best solution I found was in the answer for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet

Comment: Have to give the credit to the people who found the duplicate question just about exactly what I needed, big thanks!! been looking for this for ages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to achieve what you want:

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(Data.Quote).GetProperty(sortName);

ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "s");
MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);
LambdaExpression sort = Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);

MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(
                                         typeof(Queryable),
                                         "OrderBy",
                                         new[] {typeof(T), property.Type},
                                         Query.Expression,
                                         Expression.Quote(sort));

var orderedQuery = (IOrderedQueryable<T>)Query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(call);

PaginatedList = orderedQuery.Skip(skipValue).Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: This works as well by sorting in one direction but `source.Expression` needs to be `Query.Expression` really short hand solution

Comment: Mind the naming convention should be lowercase `query` in my code above as it is a variable

Comment: Fixed variable name. `Query` is how the variable is named on OP.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of that you need to create an expression to select that property.From this [source](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/817372/Building-OrderBy-Lambda-Expression-from-Property-N):

```
public static class Utility
{
    //makes expression for specific prop
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, object>> GetExpression<TSource>(string propertyName)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
        Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property
        (param, propertyName), typeof(object));   //important to use the Expression.Convert
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(conversion, param);
    }


    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> 
    OrderBy<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string propertyName)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(GetExpression<TSource>(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then you can order by as I show below:

```
var result=Query.OrderBy(sortName)...;
```

Answer (score 1):

The value being copied in to `propertyInfo` is just an Object, as that is the type returned by `GetProperty()`.  Hover over `var` and you will confirm this.

The `GetValue` method doesn't exist for an Object, so you need to cast it to the right type before making the call to `GetValue`.