# EfCore 3.1.3 throwing Execption for OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to Order by a query using the following efcore query

> Getting the PropertyInfo for the column which needs to be orderedBy using this below

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(TableVM).GetProperty("Type");
```

> The EfCore Query

```
db.Table
 **//LinkKit Extension Method**
 .AsExpandable()
 .Where(whereClause)
 .Select(m => new TableVM
 {
    id= m.Id,
    name = m.Name,
    description = m.Description,
    type = m.Type,
    status = m.Status
})
**// Conversion of the OrderBy fails, which throws an exception saying it can't convert it into Linq query.**
.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null))
.Skip(skip)
.Take(take)
.ToList();
```

---

[C# - code to order by a property using the property name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689199/c-sharp-code-to-order-by-a-property-using-the-property-name-as-a-string)

This works in EfCore 2.

Tested with removing the LinqKit extension in EfCore 3.1.3, it throws error only for OrderBy stating it can't convert it into Linq

Am I doing any mistake in the EfCore Query? Thanks in advance

Comment: EF doesn't know how to translate that code into an SQL query, you can't use reflection like this I'm afraid. EF Core 2 would have given you warnings about this in the logs and then done everything in memory rather than in the database.

Comment: Don't use the accepted answer from the link, because it doesn't work for `IQueryable`. Instead, use some of the `IQueryable` / expression based answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - code to order by a property using the property name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689199/c-sharp-code-to-order-by-a-property-using-the-property-name-as-a-string)

Comment: I am still learning efcore, but we get the entity in the memory after we do things like .ToList() or .AsEnumerable() right?

So EfCore 2 was converting this query all along to a Linq and executing on the Db right.

The issue I am facing is I need to OrderBy to get things in Alphabetical order. Wondering that is possible?

Comment: @DavidG I have use the first answer the Reflection one for my query. It is working in EfCore 2 but not in EfCore 3.1.3

Comment: Like Ivan said, don't use that one, use the other answers.

Comment: EF Core 2 was NOT converting such conditions to SQL, but was executing the, in memory after retrieving the unfiltered data from the database. The so called client evaluation feature, which was giving you wrong impression at the same time affecting negatively performance, so it has been removed in EF Core 3.0+. That's why now you have to use translatable constructs or explicitly switch to `IEnumerable` methods. And `IQueryable` / expression based solutions are translatable.

Comment: If it would be easier for you, take the code from my answer [How to use a string to create a EF order by expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908403/how-to-use-a-string-to-create-a-ef-order-by-expression/39916384#39916384).

Comment: @IvanStoev @DavidG IQueryable worked! Thanks. But just to understand EfCore well

`private static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
`

Reflections is not a good choice for Linq Conversions. It is safe to say EfCore 2 was throwing warning and in EfCore 3.1.3 it openly rejects it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo.

Your TableVM class has `type` property and your Entity has `Type` property.

So, renaming the property in TableVM class should work.