# How to use Reflection in linq queries ?RSS

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm looking for a way to use reflection in my linq queries to increase code reusability. for example, i want to change this method :

```
private Orders GetObjectGraph(MyDbContext dbContext, int orderID)
{
    return dbContext.Orders.Include(o => o.OrderDetails).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderID == orderID);
}
```

To something like this :

```
private object GetObjectGraph(MyDbContext dbContext, string masterEntityName, string detailsEntityName, string masterFieldName, object masterFieldValue)
{
    return dbContext[masterEntityName].Include(o => o[detailsEntityName]).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(o => o.[masterFieldName] == masterFieldValue);
}
```

Can anybody help me how to accomplish this task ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I’d stay away from reflection, but sounds like a use case for generic methods, maybe with a little specification pattern built in. Check out eShopOnWeb for an implementation

Comment: Do you only have the string names for the entities? Because if you know the entity type at the moment of the call you could replace the `string` parameters by with `Expressions` and add a generic type to identify the root entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this (if you are not getting strings from somewhere outside in runtime, if you do than this solution can be adapted to build corresponding [Expression Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) from strings):

```
private T GetObjectGraph<T, TDetails, TField>(
    MyDbContext dbContext,
    Expression<Func<T, TDetails>> details,
    Expression<Func<T, TField>> field,
    TField value) where T: class
{
    var p = field.Parameters[0];
    var eq = Expression.Equal(field.Body, Expression.Constant(value));
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(eq, p); 
    return dbContext
        .Set<T>()
        .Include(details)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefault(expr);
}
```

And usage:

```
GetObjectGraph(dbContext, (Order o) => o.OrderDetails, o => o.OrderID, orderID)
```

If you don't need to parse strings and so on this could be simplified to:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static T GetObjectGraph<T, TDetails>(
        this DbSet<T> set, 
        Expression<Func<T, TDetails>> details,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter) where T : class
    {

        return set
            .Include(details)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault(filter);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
dbContext.Orders(o => o.OrderDetails, o => o.OrderID == orderID);
```

And for more insight how to handle strings you can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39916384/2501279).

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i think you missing 'masterEntityName' in your sample. Can you provide more description that what's happened? Thanks